# How can I filter each subset of a dataframe for 2 conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I need to check 2 conditions for sales data:

1. was sold in specific years
2. was sold on specific amount of days with amount > 0

Dataframe df:

```
date       | id  | qual | amount
2020-09-01 | 123 | A    | 100
2020-09-02 | 123 | A    | 0
2020-09-03 | 123 | A    | 90
2020-09-04 | 123 | A    | 80
2020-09-01 | 123 | B    | 8
2020-09-02 | 123 | B    | 6
2020-09-03 | 123 | B    | 4
2020-09-04 | 123 | B    | 2
2021-02-01 | 123 | B    | 18
2020-02-01 | 456 | A    | 96
2021-02-02 | 456 | A    | 90
2021-01-01 | 789 | A    | 30
2021-01-02 | 789 | A    | 31
2021-01-03 | 789 | A    | 32
2021-01-04 | 789 | A    | 29
```

The data frame has 10_000 IDs with ~1000 dates for each ID and 1 or 2 quality (qual) levels per ID.

The check needs to be performed for every combination of ID + qual level.

After I check each ID + Qual I want to filter my dataframe so that it only contains IDs + Qual combinations that passed that check.

> ID: 123 with qual: A

- has year 2020 and year 2021 in sales ❌
- has at least 4 rows with amount > 0 ❌
- -> does not pass

> ID: 123 with qual: B

- has year 2020 and year 2021 in sales ✅
- has at least 4 rows with amount > 0 ✅
- -> does pass

> ID: 456 with qual: A

- has year 2020 and year 2021 in sales ✅
- has at least 4 rows with amount > 0 ❌
- -> does not pass

> ID: 789 with qual: A

- has year 2020 and year 2021 in sales ❌
- has at least 4 rows with amount > 0 ✅
- -> does not pass

Result should therefor look like this:

```
date       | id  | qual | amount
2020-09-01 | 123 | B    | 8
2020-09-02 | 123 | B    | 6
2020-09-03 | 123 | B    | 4
2020-09-04 | 123 | B    | 2
2021-02-01 | 123 | B    | 18
```

My code so far:

```
required_sales_years= [2020, 2021]
required_sales_days = 4

has_required_sales = []
for id in df["id"].unique().tolist():
    for qual in df["qual"].unique().tolist():
        temp = df.query(
            "id== @id and qual == @qual and amount > 0"
        )
        sales_years = temp["date"].dt.year.unique().tolist()
        check_sales_year = all(item in sales_years for item in required_sales_years)
        check_sales_days = len(temp.index) >= required_sales_days
        if check_sales_year and check_sales_days:
            has_required_sales.append((id, qual))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby().transform` to count the valid sales:

```
required_sale_years = [2020, 2021]
required_sales_days = 4

# intermediate variables
df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
df['valid'] = df['year'].isin(required_sales_years) & df['amount'].gt(0)

# groupby
groups = df.groupby(['id','qual'])

has_years = groups['year'].transform(lambda x: set(required_sales_years).issubset(set(x)))
valid_sales = groups['valid'].transform('sum') >= required_sales_days

output = df[has_years & valid_sales]
```

Output:

```
        date   id qual  amount  year  valid
4 2020-09-01  123    B       8  2020   True
5 2020-09-02  123    B       6  2020   True
6 2020-09-03  123    B       4  2020   True
7 2020-09-04  123    B       2  2020   True
8 2021-02-01  123    B      18  2021   True
```

Comment: This is good but you are missing the condition on the date field to check that the year is 2020

Comment: I think you you need to include the year in the group by somehow and have the original date back on the index

Comment: @Robert I see, missed that part. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but you only check if test["date"].dt.year.isin(required_sale_years), which would pass if there are only sales in 2020.

Comment: I don't understand your point? Aren't you only count (positive) sales within those years? Or do positive sales in other years also count?

Comment: If you remove row "2021-02-01 | 123 | B | 18" your code would still pass id:123, qual:B even if there are no sales in 2021 anymore.